# saving an image to documents directory - not working - only creating a zero byte file

Tags: uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to make a simple app to take a picture and save the file to both a UIImageview and to the documents folder so it can be recalled at a later time as the UIImageview.  To get visibility into if the app is actually making a file, I have turned on Application supports iTunes File sharing within the .plist file.

Problem is the file generated is zero bytes.  I have tried both PNG and JPG format.

```
- (IBAction)picImage:(id)sender {
imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.delegate = self;

//check to see if the device has camera capability
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
{
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

}
else
{
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
}

[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    //set the UIImageView to the selected image
    playerImage.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    //obtaining saving path
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *imagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"player.png"];

    UIImage *editedImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(editedImage);
    //NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(editedImage,1.0);

    // This actually creates the image at the file path specified, with the image's NSData.
   [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:imagePath contents:imageData attributes:nil];

    //dismiss the imagepicker view controller
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code and let me know is it working or not..!!!!

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *strimagename;
    strimagename=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Test.jpg"];


NSString *thumbFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:strimagename];
UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
NSData *thumbData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1);
[thumbData writeToFile:thumbFilePath atomically:YES];
[imgPicker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

This code will save image in documentory folder..

Happy Coding..!!!!!!

Comment: Thanks!  That worked with two small modifications to the last line.  I had to change imgPicker to self and change the deprecated dismissModal... function to the updated one. - [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];